# Error while using type provider 'FSharp.Configuration.ResourceProvider'

Tags: .net, f#, resx, type-providers

I just loaded `FSharp.Configuration` in paket files and created a type with

```
open FSharp.Configuration
type ResourceProvider = ResXProvider<file="Resources/Strings.resx">
```

In `Strings.resx` are resources with e.g.:

```
<data name="Greeting" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Hello</value>
</data>
```

Everything compiles.
But when I call that resource through the provider with `ResourceProvider.Greeting` I get this error:

```
error FS3033: The type provider 'FSharp.Configuration.ConfigTypeProvider+FSharpConfigurationProvider' 
reported an error in the context of provided type: 
'FSharp.Configuration.ResXProvider,file="Resources/Strings.resx"', member 'get_Greeting'. 
Error: Method 'System.Object readValue[Object](System.String, System.Reflection.Assembly,
 System.String)' not found in type '<null>'. This method may be missing in the types 
available in the target assemblies.
```

Can anyone help me with that error message? I found no solution to this message.

Thanks.

Edit: it's a .NET 6 project.

Comment: I'm getting the same thing and am trying to figure out why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After browsing the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.Configuration), I think the problem is that ResXProvider doesn't yet support .NET 5 (let alone .NET 6). The [ResXProvider test file](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.Configuration/blob/master/tests/FSharp.Configuration.Tests/ResXProvider.Tests.fs) has a compiler directive that limits it to .NET 4.6.1, and there's an [open issue](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.Configuration/issues/156) about missing support for .NET Core.

As an alternative, I suggest using `Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream` instead.

Comment: Yes, I came to the same result. I saw compiler directive, too.
I read that this type provider is a bit complicated to migrate to .NET.

Thanks for pointing out an alternative way.